# Using liquibase parameter inside loadData CSV

Tags: liquibase

I want to abstract functions for generating uuid for each dbms:

```
<property name="uuid_function" value="gen_random_uuid()" dbms="postgresql"/>
<property name="uuid_function" value="NEWID()" dbms="mssql"/>
<property name="uuid_function" value="sys_guid()" dbms="oracle"/>
```

And then using this property in my CSV which is loaded by loadData like this:

```
"${uuid_function}"
```

But it is not working (parse error on $). The other approach with default values on column inside loadData:

```
<column name="id" type="COMPUTED" defaultValueComputed="${uuid_function}"/>
```

..is also not working. Id column is defined as NOT NULL and if I leave the column out of my CSV it complains that columns can't be null, even tho it should use the default value.

How do I use parameters inside my CSV files and/or why is the default value failing me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it working very similar as you describe, so I think it can help you, but instead with a `UUID`, in my case it is with a `Date`, any way, the same case.

In my changelog, I have a property to calculate current date:

```
<property name="now" value="CURRENT_DATE" dbms="hsqldb" />
```

Then, I have a user table which is created with this changeSet:

```
<changeSet author="miguel" id="1448735850226-1">
    <createTable tableName="usuario">
        <column name="login" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="oid" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
        <column name="fecha" type="date" defaultValueComputed="${now}">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="nombre" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
        <column name="apellidos" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
        <column name="activo" type="BOOLEAN"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

As you can see, `fecha` column is not null and it has `defaultValueComputed` attribute to `${now}` function.

I have a `users.csv` file that create test users (`usuarios-test.csv`):

```
login;oid;nombre;apellidos;activo
user;b776052e-7c9f-11e5-8584-67d602646e6f;Prueba;Prueba;true
```

As you can see, in the csv file I use headers line and I don't include `fecha` field. (*In my case, `UUID` are pre-generated, but I could change it as you are*).

Finally I have this `loadData` change

```
<changeSet author="miguel" id="1448735850226-16">
    <loadData tableName="usuario" encoding="UTF-8" 
      file="src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/usuarios-test.csv"
      quotchar="'" separator=";" >
      <column header="login" name="login" type="STRING"/>
      <column header="oid" name="oid" type="STRING"/>
      <column header="nombre" name="nombre" type="STRING"/>
      <column header="apellidos" name="apellidos" type="STRING"/>
      <column header="activo" name="activo" type="BOOLEAN"/>
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

As you can see, I declared all columns present into `.csv` file and `fecha` is not included, so `defaultValueComputed` works and I get users created with current date.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Basically, had to remove column from loadData and move default value to create changeset and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

`type="COMPUTED"` is wrong. You need to use a correct datatype, but as the datatype for a UUID is different between the DBMS, you also need to create a property for that as well.

The following works for me in Oracle and Postgres:

```
  <property name="uuid_function" value="gen_random_uuid()" dbms="postgresql"/>
  <property name="uuid_function" value="NEWID()" dbms="mssql"/>
  <property name="uuid_function" value="sys_guid()" dbms="oracle"/>

  <property name="uuid_type" value="uuid" dbms="postgresql"/>
  <property name="uuid_type" value="uniqueidentifier" dbms="mssql"/>
  <property name="uuid_type" value="RAW(32)" dbms="oracle"/>

  <changeSet author="testing" id="1">
    <createTable tableName="foo">
      <column name="id" type="${uuid_type}" defaultValueComputed="${uuid_function}">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
```

This generates the following table in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
   id  uuid    DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
);
```

and in Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO
(
   ID  RAW(32)   DEFAULT sys_guid() NOT NULL
);
```